# phpexcel how get cell format

Tags: php, phpexcel

How I can get cell format? 
I Try

```
$E->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 24)->getCalculatedValue()
```

but it rerurns '6', I need '6 бухта' (sorry for russian letters)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$E->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 24)
    ->getFormattedValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the cell format by code,

```
var_dump($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D3')->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode());
```

and output will be like:

### string(8) "mm-dd-yy"